# Break lines on references (book title) within biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking, biblatex-chicago

I'm putting the bibliography but I have a problem with the book's references. If the book title is too long this doesn't break to the next line. I've looked it only occurs with `@book`, whereas `@Inbook`, `@article`, `@inproceedings` it's ok.

[image]

## my configuration

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{egameps}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


% subsubsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsubsection{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{mathptmx}

\hypersetup{%
   colorlinks = {true},
   urlcolor = {black},
   linkcolor = {black},
   citecolor = {black},
}

\newenvironment{conditions*}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

%%%%%
%BIB
%%%%%

\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}

\usepackage[authordate, numbermonth=false,
            backend=biber, noibid, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{%
   \mkbibbrackets{\ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1\isdot}}{#1\isdot}}}

\begin{filecontents}{bib_test.bib}
@book{Valero_test,
author = {Valero, Antonio and Valero, Alicia},
isbn = {9814273937},
month = {aug},
publisher = { World Scientific Publishing Company },
title = {{Thanatia: The destiny of the Earth's mineral resources - A Thermodynamic Cradle to Cradle Assessment}},
year = {2014}
}
@Inbook{Fare1994,
author = {F{\"{a}}re, Rolf and Grosskopf, Shawna and Lindgren, Bj{\"{o}}rn and Roos, Pontus},
booktitle = {Data Envelopment Analysis: Theory, Methodology, and Applications},
doi = {10.1007/978-94-011-0637-5_13},
isbn = {978-0-7923-9480-8},
pages = {253--272},
publisher = {Springer, Dordrecht},
title = {{Productivity Developments in Swedish Hospitals: A Malmquist Output Index Approach}},
year = {1994}
}
@inproceedings{Lisitsa2019,
author = {Lisitsa, Svetlana and Levina, Anastasia and Lepekhin, Aleksander},
booktitle = {E3S Web of Conferences},
doi = {10.1051/E3SCONF/201911002061},
issn = {2267-1242},
month = {aug},
pages = {1--10},
title = {{Supply-chain management in the oil industry}},
volume = {110},
year = {2019}
}
@book{Schuschny2007,
author = {Schuschny, Andr{\'{e}}s},
isbn = {9789213230152},
mendeley-groups = {KarlaArias},
number = {46},
pages = {1--53},
series={Estudios estad{\'\i}sticos y prospectivos},
publisher = {CEPAL},
title = {{M{\'{e}}todo DEA y su aplicaci{\'{o}}n al estudio del sector energ{\'{e}}tico y las emisiones de CO2 en Am{\'{e}}rica Latina y el Caribe}},
year = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib_test.bib}
%%%%%
%
%%%%%


\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}\caption*{#1}}

\lhead{}
\cfoot{}                                    % left header: document author
\rfoot{\large\thepage}                      % center footer: page number
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000 \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\def\qed{{\quad \vrule height 5pt width 5pt depth 0pt}}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}



\begin{document}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname:poss}{#1's}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias
  \textcite}

\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias
  \textcites}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}

\autocite{Fare1994, Lisitsa2019, Schuschny2007, Valero_test} bla bla.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\begin{singlespace}
\printbibliography
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

- note: I think it has to do with `\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `sloppy` – you may need to delete the `\usepackage{ulem}` command because this package blocks the hyphenation. Once the package is deleted, the hyphenation will work as normal:

[image]